# Numerical stability of Smith normal form computation

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, numerical-methods

I have been trying to find a paper that clearly states this, but I was not able to. 
Do the SNF computation methods suffer from numerical instability?

It is known that SNF is slower than an SVD computation, but are there more numerical issue for SNF computation, as the size/density of the matrix grows, compared to SVD?

Of course if you have a reference that discuss possible numerical issues, I would appreciate the title and/or link.

Comment: If you abandon orthogonal transformations in favour of general nonsingular transformations, then it is entirely possible for errors to grow without bound. It is not certain that it will happen, we are just not sure that it will not. Smith's normal form is useful for theoretical work, but I have never seen it used from practical calculations. I would be happy to the references that you seek, but I am just not sure they exists. Orthogonal transformations are nice because they perserve the Euclidian norm of any error instead of magnifying it.

Comment: @Carl Christian - SNF is used in practice for homology computation (e.g. homology of a simplicial complex). https://ljk.imag.fr/membres/Jean-Guillaume.Dumas/Publications/DHSW.pdf Of course, for large scale complexes SNF scales really poorly in terms of computation, and that's why there are methods that enable to 'collapse' faces white retaining the same homology classes.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference. When you referred to the singular value decomposition I erroneously assumed that your matrices consisted of general floating point numbers rather than integers.